# picasso image size is coming up small

Tags: android, picasso

I have an imageview with the standard XML format: apply this xml to gridviewlist.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/grid_regular_image"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/none"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/grid_item_image"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/default_numbers"
    android:textColor="@color/grid_text"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


   </RelativeLayout>
```

I am getting the image from an API and applying it to picasso. Like this:

```
Picasso.with(getContext().getApplicationContext()).load(pd.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.none).error(R.drawable.none).centerCrop().resize(230, 230).into(holder.image);
```

The images when displayed on GridView are coming really small? I am not sure why this is happening - this is happening even though the size is big?

Not sure what is wrong here? Can somebody help me fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: `resize(230, 230)` is making this 230 by 230 pixels, not dp - is that what you intend?

Comment: My picture size 230 * 230. I would like to have same size to shown on my imageView, are you saying pixel show are different from DP? What is recommended?

Comment: Try using `.fit()`. What that does is resize the image to fit the imageview being displayed. Since you know the size of your image, I'd suggest the imageview xml have the sizes explicitly set to 230dp width and height. Picasso should then try to make the image fit that size when you call `.fit()`

Answer (score 2):

Same problem with me, problem exists in ImageAdapter class. Do not use `.fit()` and comment `imageView.setLayoutParams, imageView.setScaleType and imageView.setPadding`. Then it will be all good. Hope it helps

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
       // imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(185, 185));
       // imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        //imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    String url = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780//nBNZadXqJSdt05SHLqgT0HuC5Gm.jpg";
    //imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    Picasso.with(this.mContext)
            .load(url)
           // .fit()
            //.resize(100, 100)
            .into(imageView);
    return imageView;
}
```